# Efficient way to communicate with sockets by passing model objects between them

Tags: java, android, sockets, model-view

I'm trying to conceptualize how to communicate and sync the data between my view tablets and the server.

Fist let me describe the set up:
I have several tablets running the same app that can choose to display any view in particular. A main server contains the models for all those views and manipulates the data in those models. The tablets will only be used to display said data and send back touch inputs.

If I understand sockets well enough, you can send entire serialized objects through a network from a java server to an android device.

As a result, this made me come up with the following way to handle the situation:
I will have the same model object per view on the server, and have the same model object on the tablet. Both the server and the tablets will contain their own controllers for those models/ views. 
Every second or so, the tablets will send back the state of their model object to the server, which will change the states of all the model objects if necessary, and send those objects back out to be displayed.

A big issue that I see with this, is what will happen when a model is changed by two different sources, I'd have to figure out some merging methods which seems like a wee bit of hassle, but doable. Also, having it update once per second, I wonder if that will cause a noticeable lag or not.

Are there better ideas as far as how to accomplish this type of communication, perhaps a well known pattern?

Comment: Why not use a database to keep track of changes and user inputs? That way you could also distribute the latest changes to the other tablets.

Comment: Oh, a database. Could you describe in a bit more detail, the logistics of that?
Like, can several things edit it at the same time? And where is is located, logically.

Comment: The database would be running on the server, as the server distributes changes frome one tablet to the others (if i understand you idea the right way). The server itself should handle changes one after another, so it's impossible that two changes happen at the exact same time. You would always distribute the changes, that were recognized most recently by the server.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see. That may work, however, this obfuscates the idea of how the tablets will send back the changes/action performed stuff.